# How to access object variable name in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I Have scope variable

```
$scope.variableName = "content";
$scope.content['key'] = 'value';
```

In HTML I can  access content value in ng-if statement as content['key']

But i want to access the same using variableName string, i.e variable name of the object that i am using in ng-if condition in HTML

Like `{{variableName}}['key']`

Is this possible or can be achieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take reference to `$scope` via `this` keyword:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.variableName = "content";
  $scope.content = {};
  $scope.content['key'] = 'value';  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js">
</script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  {{this[variableName]['key']}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access using `{{content["key"]}}` as well with `{{content.key}}`.

```js
var module = angular.module("myModule", []);

module.controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.variableName = "content";
  $scope.content = {};
  $scope.content['key'] = 'value';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myModule">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    {{content["key"]}} <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is not i am looking for